# wix conditions that are true - are failing

Tags: wix

I have two cases of this problem. First I have:

```
Custom Action="InstallXla" After="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[ExcelInstalled="yes"]]></Custom>
```

And in the log from the install I have:

```
PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ExcelInstalled property. Its value is 'yes'.
... 
Skipping action: InstallXla (condition is false)
```

I also have:

```
   <CustomTable Id="_VsdLaunchCondition">
      <Column Id="Condition" Type="string" Width="255" PrimaryKey="yes" />
      <Column Id="Description" Localizable="yes" Type="string" Width="255" />
      <Column Id="Url" Type="string" Width="0" />

      <!-- Wrong Office bitness -->
      <Row>
        <Data Column="Condition"><![CDATA[OfficeBitness="32" OR SKIPCHECKS="1"]]></Data>
        <Data Column="Description">[LocUITextRequireX64]</Data>
        <Data Column="Url"><![CDATA[http://rpt.me/WRDownloads]]></Data>
      </Row>

      <!-- Require word version 14 or greater (office 2010) -->
      <Row>
        <Data Column="Condition"><![CDATA[WORD_VER >= 14 OR SKIPCHECKS="1"]]></Data>
        <Data Column="Description">[LocUITextRequireMSOffice]</Data>
        <Data Column="Url"><![CDATA[http://rpt.me/WRDownloads]]></Data>
      </Row>
   </CustomTable>
```

And the log has:

```
OfficeBitness property. Its value is '32'. 
WORD_VER property. Its value is '16'.
```

The require word version test passes (no prompt saying the word version is too old). But the bitness prompt does come up.

Is there something I need to do to make string comparisons work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is - it must be all upper case to be seen elsewhere in the script.

So make OfficeBitness OFFICE_BITNESS.